# How to redirect standard output to multiple commands in Fish?

Tags: fish, tee

This question is the same as this one, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-can-i-send-stdout-to-multiple-commands, but pertains to the Fish shell. I'd like to extract multiple field values from some JSON output and saving them to different files. Here is an example that works in Bash:

```bash
bash-3.2$ echo '{"foo": "bar", "baz": "bam"}' | tee >(jq -r '.foo' > foo.txt) >(jq -r '.baz' > baz.txt)
{"foo": "bar", "baz": "bam"}
```

Note that the files have been save successfully:

```
bash-3.2$ cat foo.txt
bar
bash-3.2$ cat baz.txt
bam
```

However, if I attempt to do the same in Fish, it hangs:

```
> echo '{"foo": "bar", "baz": "bam"}' | tee >(jq '.foo' > foo.txt) >(jq '.bar' > bar.txt)
```

Any idea what the differene between Fish and Bash is that is causing this?

Comment: It would appear that this is the topic of this "Process substitution, the other way around" open issue (https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1786).

Comment: "Any idea what the differene between Fish and Bash is that is causing this" -- it is merely unimplemented in fish. fish's [`psub`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/psub.html) is the equivalent of bash's `<(...)` but fish has no `>(...)` variant

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code block to leverage `tee`'s stream duplicating ability in order to direct one of the streams to `stderr` (one will still be directed to `stdout` as normal), and pipe them separately into their respective commands:

```bash
echo {\"foo\": \"bar\"\,
      \"baz\": \"bam\"} |
begin tee /dev/stderr 2>|
      jq -r .foo>foo.txt
end | jq -r .baz>baz.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

For the time being use [pee](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pee):

```
echo '{"foo": "bar", "baz": "bam"}' | pee "jq '.foo' > foo.txt" "jq '.bar' > bar.txt"
```